# how to pass useState state value to useReducer initialstate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to pass a value from useState state value to useReducer initialstate.

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

const initialState = {
    menuOpen: true,
    promoOpen: false,
    couponOpen: false,
    cartOpen: false,
    orderOpen: false,
    orderAmount: 1,
    filteredItem: item,
  };

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

const fetchUrl = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    const respData = await resp.json();
    const item = respData.item;
    const category = respData.category;
    const promo = respData.promo;
    setItem(item);
    setCategory(category);
    setPromo(promo);
    setFilterItem(item);
  };
```

But when I do `console.log(state.filteredItem)`, I got an empty array so I assume that it didn't pass the value to the initialState. Is there a way for me to pass a useState state value to useReducer initialState value?
Thanks before

Comment: I don't understand, the behaviour you described is correct. `item` is initially an empty array, which means `filteredItem` is initially an empty array, since you do `filteredItem: item`. So when you print it via `console.log(state.filteredItem)` it will print an empty array. What are you expecting it to print?

Comment: sorry I forgot about my fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do here will not work.  The initial state of the reducer is just that -- the **INITIAL** state.  It will use the value of `initialState` from the very first render, before your `items` has been updated with the fetch results.  Changes to the variable `initialState` will not effect the reducer after it has already been created.  You have to `dispatch` an action to store the `items` in your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

You declared your state with an empty array therefore that's what filteredItem shows. If you've set your state later on, in order to change it in the reducer I think you need to use dispatch function.

Comment: sorry I forgot about my fetch